# Center align text wit

Tags: css, reactjs, alignment

I'm trying to create a React component that looks like this:

[image: Bike description component]

I'm not sure how to correctly align the text with CSS as displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can look something like this:

```css
.leftText {
text-align:right;
min-width:100px;
display:inline-block;
}
.space {
padding-left:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="leftText">Text 1</span><span class="space">Text 2</span><br>
<span class="leftText">TextText 1</span><span class="space">Text 2</span><br>
<span class="leftText">Text 1</span><span class="space">Text 2</span><br>
<span class="leftText">TextTextText 1</span><span class="space">Text 2</span><br>
<span class="leftText">Text 1</span><span class="space">Text 2</span><br>
```